# Putting each n elements of a list in another list

Tags: matlab

I have a list with 10 elements. I want to put each 2 elements in a list. How do I write the code?

```
P = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

I want the result as below:

```
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [9 10]]
```

Comment: Use the built-in function `reshape`.

Comment: should I write X=reshape(P,1,2)?

Comment: I hope you have spent the last 20 minutes figuring out how to use `reshape` and have not been sitting twiddling your thumbs waiting for me to tell you what to write.  Matlab is interactive so interact.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are already there: `isequal([[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [9 10]],[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10])` I suppose you actually want something like `[[1 2]; [3 4]; [5 6]; [7 8]; [9 10]]`

Answer (score 3):

...too many possibilities...must...resist...itching...fingers...

```
>> P = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
>> P1 = reshape(P, 2,[])
>> P2 = P([1:2:end; 2:2:end])
>> P3 = mat2cell(P, 1, 2*ones(numel(P)/2,1))
>> P4 = zeros(2, numel(P)/2, class(P));  P4(:) = P
>> P5 = [P(1:2:end); P(2:2:end)]
>> P6 = accumarray([round(0.5:0.5:numel(P)/2)' repmat([1;2],numel(P)/2,1)], P)
>> P7 = cat(1 , P(1:2:end), P(2:2:end))
```

...dang.

Answer (score 1):

Because I feel kind today, here's how to do it via reshape.

```
out = reshape(P,2,[])';
```

The reshape call creates a 2-by-n array where the elements are distributed (1,1), (2,1), (1,2) etc. The transpose then flips rows and columns to produce the desired result.